# Can't output Float values to text file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, output

My code currently produces an array (ra) containing only float values. If a value in this array meets a certain condition, I want to output that specific value to a text file. Here is the part of my code in question:

```
outputFile = open('outFile.txt', 'wb')
i = 0
membersOuter = []
membersInner = []
membersCore = []
while i < (len(ra)):
    DiffFinal = Diff[i] * 3600 * kpc_per_arcsec / 1000 #just converting values from an array called Diff
    if DiffFinal < 2.0:
        membersOuter.append(ra[i])
    if DiffFinal < 1.0:
        membersInner.append(ra[i])
    if DiffFinal < 0.5:
        membersCore.append(ra[i])
        outputFile.write(ra[i] + ' ') #this is the part causing problems
    i += 1
```

The code successfully creates arrays for the 3 member categories. However, I want to be able to output the ra values (which are all floats) meeting the final condition to outFile.txt. When I run this code I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' does not support the buffer interface
```

I am using Python 3.4, and searching past questions told me this process has changed since lower versions. Some changes that were recommended included:

```
outputFile.write(str(ra[i]))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

and

```
outputFile.write(bytes(ra[i]))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `str(ra[i]).encode('ascii')` or `bytes(str(ra[i]),'ascii')`?

Comment: is there an easier way to include spaces/new lines than having to put `outputFile.write(str(ra[i]).encode('ascii') + ' \n'.encode('ascii'))`

Comment: If it is a text file, why are you opening it with `wb`?

Comment: yes, if someone in the future is reading this, use 'w', not 'wb'. Although vaultah's suggestion does work if you go with 'wb'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String formatting should help with both of your problems. Here is your example, with some irrelevant parts removed:

```
ra = [1.5, 2.1, 3.3, 11./7]

outputFile = open('outFile.txt', 'w')
for i in range(4):
    outputFile.write('{} \n'.format(ra[i]))
```

Notice:

- The output text file is open for text, not binary, `w`, not `wb`
- The float variable is formatted by the `{}` directive inside the string.
- The whitespace and newline are easily included in the format string.

Comment: switched to 'w' after your comment and looking at a mode chart - just saw an example like mine online using 'wb' (beginner here). I also got this working to add another array in a separate column by just putting `outputFile.write('{} \n'.format(y[i]))` below the first outputFile.write command (took the \n out of the ra one). Thanks for the help